# Min and IFError

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a pretty large excel file that I do calculation percentages on. for most fields I use `=IFERROR(D34/J34,0)`

However, I have one field where duplicates may play a factor however are not a negative but I don't count anything over 100%. For those columns I use `=MIN(100%,H18/J18)` however I get the standard "#DIV/0!" if no data exists. I was wondering how I might use =min + IFError in my use case.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just nest one formula in the other:

```
=IFERROR(MIN(100%,H18/J18),0)
```